# express-flash messages are empty after refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, flash-message

The express-flash module does not work correctly. When I add a message, it's empty on the next page refresh.

This is a part of my app.js:

```
var flash = require('express-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard ctrl',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}))
app.use(flash());
app.get( '/', login);
```

And this is in my login module

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.flash('error'));
    req.flash('error','Test errors!');
    res.render('user_login');
};
```

The log output is always an empty array when I refresh the page multiple times.

Comment: When you say refresh, do you mean when you render `user_login` or you land on it and then reload the page?

Comment: I mean reloading page in the browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`express-flash` extends `connect-flash` so you don't require a redirect (or a new page load) before the flash messages are available.

It does so by patching `res.render()` to retrieve all flash messages, so they become available as `messages` inside your templates.

However, after retrieving all flash messages, the list of messages will be emptied, because it is assumed that when they are retrieved, they are used. That's how `connect-flash` works.

So after calling `res.render` in your login handler, the list of messages will be empty.

Having a list of flash messages persist across page reloads isn't trivial to implement, because you have to determine if something is a reload or a "normal" page load.

Comment: Oh, I see. then how can I display an error message on the next reload? After processing POST requests, the page should be redirected to the form. Then how can I send error or success message? Are all messages available in the next render?

Comment: In that case, I think you'd want to use `connect-flash` instead of `express-flash`.

Comment: connect-flash is exactly what I need. But what's express flash? When should I use it?

Comment: `express-flash` uses `connect-flash` but doesn't require a page reload before you can access the flash messages.